# Java iOS MDM : APNs Certificate UID changes

Tags: java, ios, apple-push-notifications, mdm

We have an end-to-end iOS MDM implementation developed.
Now, I have a requirement that each customer (tenant) should have its own APNs certificate which will be used for sending push notification.
Using java I have created a .CSR referring the iOS Vendor CSR Signing Link which is used to create a Customer.CSR.

Using the Apple's Identity Portal then created the .pem file which is of format MDM_ <Vendor_Name> _Certificate.pem.

**Query:**

1. Say dated 28-10-2014, I uploaded the Customer.CSR to the identity portal and got MdM_Vendor_Certificate.pem (saved it on my local desktop as **cert1.pem**).
2. Say dated 29-10-2014, I uploaded the same Customer.CSR to the identity portal and got MdM_Vendor.Certificate.pem (saved it on my local desktop as **cert2.pem**).

Now when read both the certificate contents:
i find that cert1.pem has UID = **com.apple.mgmt.External.26b...** (lets call it as **topic1**)

and cert2.pem has UID = **com.apple.mgmt.External.271..** (lets call it as **topic2**)

i.e. both the UID's are different.

So my question is:

As UID is used in **Topic** field of the MDM Payload which is internally used by APNs for sending push notifications.

1. Now Say I have installed an MDM Profile on the **device with topic1** and till the time **cert1.pem** was used for APNs the device will receive push notifications as the UID match with topic in that case.

But,

2. Say When customer renews the APNs certificate the UID changes to topic2 and the certificate used will be cert2.pem, but the **device still has** mdm profile with topic1 installed (We will not be re-installing the MDM Profile on device i assume).

So how will the device (with topic1) receive push notifications as the APNs will now get certificate with topic2. Or is it handled by APNs that it will map all the devices with topic1 to topic2.

I am unsure about this behavior of APNs. Please help.

I hope i made myself clear.

Thanks.

Thanks
Samreen Shaikh

Comment: Any updates.. I am really confused.. Please can someone help? Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the customer renews a certificate using the Renew button in the apple's identity portal the Topic field does not change.

If ever the apns certificate has expired then the customer needs to redo the whole procedure. Right from getting the CSR uploading it to apple's identity portal and getting back a PEM certificate. A new topic is created.

All the devices which were enrolled with old apns has to remove the old profile and re-install the mdm payload with the new apns certificate created as the topic has changed and the device will not get any apns notifications.

Comment: Just to correct, as of July 2022: in testing, _renewing_ a certificate _after_ it has expired _does not_ result in a new `UID` (`Topic`) certificate field; it remains unchanged.